# New Document button Behavior SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-parts, content-type, sharepoint-2013

In sp2013 when i have a document library web part on a page it shows a "New Document or drag files here button" when i click on the new document it opens a file browser to upload a document...

However i want it to offer me a popup with the 5 content types i have associated with the library. in other words to exhibit the behavior that the 'files' tab new document button in the ribbon shows, where new document gives me a choice between the available content types or at least creates the default content type.

thanks

Comment: I am guessing you want something like this:

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/content-types5.png

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround try editing the page and setting the views toolbar to "No Toolbar".
This will remove the option "a new document or drag to..." from displaying on the page.

In the solution I was working on at least this removed the confusion to users.

Answer (score 0):

Is drag and drop options work fine with other library  and which version of IE are you using. If the same URL you open from other computer does it works please try to open the same link on different brower to determine whether the issue is with browser or add in components. Please also check is there SharePoint DragUpload Control AvtiveX control is installed or not on add-on 
The add-on 'stsupld.UploadCtl' under 'Manage Add-ons' is it available or not. 
 'stsupld.UploadCtl' 14.0.4761.1000 (SharePoint Designer 2010). 
Please check these blogs too.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/054c23e7-e140-4b92-83cf-785381368ad7/drag-and-drop-files?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you enable content types for the document library. Why it happens and how to change it is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

Better to edit the webpart and use 'Show Toolbar'. This gives you the dropdown 'New' menu item.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/95522/2990